# If $a\equiv 4\pmod {13}$, a is integer, Find c ($0 \leq c \leq 12$) so that $c\equiv 9a\pmod {13}$

Tags: discrete-mathematics, modular-arithmetic

If $a\equiv 4\pmod {13}$, a is integer, Find c ($0 \leq c \leq 12$) so that $c\equiv 9a\pmod {13}$.

I translated these into the form of definition: 13 | a-4 and 13|c-9a, then I got stuck on it. I don't know how to solve a two variables congruence. How to solve it?

Comment: Is it a two-variable congruence? You know $a=4$. Can you solve $c\equiv 9\cdot 4\pmod{13}$?

Comment: How can you know a = 4? By guessing?

Comment: Sorry, meant $a\equiv 4$. If $a\equiv 4$ then $9a\equiv 9\cdot 4$.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If $a \equiv 4 \bmod 13$, then $9a \equiv 36 \bmod 13$.

Congruence is symmetric and transitive...

Comment: How can you multiply 9 on both sides of a congruence?

Comment: @Fan If $13\mid(a-4)$ then $13\mid9(a-4)=9a-9\cdot 4$.

Comment: Can I say that because 9 \equiv 9(mod 13)? So that I can multiply 9 on both sides?

Comment: That works too.

Comment: @ThomasAndrews Can I say that because 9 \equiv 9(mod 13)? So that I can multiply 9 on both sides?